# I am finding difficult to write a regular expression for a location element in xml schema

Tags: xml, xsd

Location element needs to accept "city, state" data(for exampler: Topsail Beach, NC), but ending up with errors. could someone help me?
Here is the code snippet.

```
  <xs:element name="Location" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z]*[ ]?[a-zA-Z]*,[ ]?[a-zA-Z]*"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
```

Comment: Where is that code snippet?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression for a string entry which should be in `"city, state"` format is :

`[a-zA-Z ]*, [a-zA-Z]*`

It matches the sample text provided by you i.e `Topsail Beach, NC`